# Error en SII Suministro Inmediato de información: "not a proxy instance"

Tags: java, aeat-sii

en otra pregunta he visto este código, referente al mismo tema:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
keyStore.load(null, null);

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keyStore, null);

TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
tlsParams.setSecureSocketProtocol("TLS");
tlsParams.setKeyManagers(kmf.getKeyManagers());

SiiService service = new SiiService();
SiiSOAP soap = service.getSuministroFactEmitidasPruebas();
((HTTPConduit)ClientProxy.getClient(soap).getConduit()).setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
```

lo estoy probando y me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a proxy instance
>  at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getInvocationHandler(Unknown Source)
>  at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(ClientProxy.java:128)
>  at com.sii.EnvioFacturas.main(EnvioFacturas.java:168)
> ```

Me podeis ayudar?

Comment: En que linea del codigo que muestras da el error?

Comment: en la última, donde pone: ((HTTPConduit)ClientProxy.getClient(soap).getConduit()).setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);

Comment: Al usar código de otra respuesta, deberías incluir el enlace, dando crédito a quien lo merece.

Answer (score 0):

A mí me funciona con este simple código.

```
    RespuestaLRFEmitidasType respuesta = null;

    System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "PATH_TO_KEYSTORE");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");

    SiiService service = new SiiService();
    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
    try {
        SiiSOAP port = service.getSuministroFactEmitidasPruebas();
        respuesta = port.suministroLRFacturasEmitidas(procesadoFacturasEmitidas());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo

Comment: Me alegro, podrías entonces valorar la respuesta? saludos